# Placing navigation items into an array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am looking for better ways to write this code. At the moment it grabs a list of all navigation items and places them into an array (using PDO).

However, as you can see, it is using two `foreach` loops to grab the subnavigation items under each parent. Is there a better way that this code can be written?

```
<ul id="nav">
    <?php
    if($grabNav = $db->prepare("SELECT caption,url,visibility,id,class,parent_id FROM navigation ORDER BY parent_id ASC, order_id ASC"))
    {
        $grabNav->execute();
        $grabNav = $grabNav->fetchAll();
        foreach($grabNav as $nav)
        {
            $visibility = true;
            switch($nav['visibility'])
            {
                default:
                case 0: $visibility = false; break;
                case 1: $visibility = true; break;
                case 2: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = true; } else { $visibility = false; } break;
                case 3: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = false; } else { $visibility = true; } break;
            }
            if(!$visibility) { continue; }
            if($nav['parent_id'] != -1) { continue; }

            $class = $core->output($nav['class']);
            if($nav['id'] == PAGE_ID) { $class .= ' selected'; }
            echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><a href="'.$core->output($nav['url']).'">'.$core->output($nav['caption'],true).'</a><ul id="subNav">';
            foreach($grabNav as $sub)
            {
                if($sub['parent_id'] == $nav['id'])
                {
                    $visibility = true;
                    switch($sub['visibility'])
                    {
                        default:
                        case 0: $visibility = false; break;
                        case 1: $visibility = true; break;
                        case 2: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = true; } else { $visibility = false; } break;
                        case 3: if(LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser)) { $visibility = false; } else { $visibility = true; } break;
                    }
                    if(!$visibility) { continue; }
                    $subClass = $core->output($sub['class']);
                    echo'<li class="'.$subClass.'"><a href="'.$core->output($sub['url']).'">'.$core->output($sub['caption'],true).'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            echo'</ul></li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Return Early**

If you extract the PHP code to a function, you can return early, and thus save a level of nesting:

```
<ul id="nav">
<?php printNavigation(); ?>
</ul>

<?php
function printNavigation() {
    if(!($grabNav = $db->prepare("SELECT caption,url,visibility,id,class,parent_id FROM navigation ORDER BY parent_id ASC, order_id ASC"))) {
        return;
    }
    [...]
    ?>
}
```

**Remove Duplication and further simplifications**

Currently, your visibility check and your one long echo line are duplicates. You can extract these to functions:

```
function isVisible($visibilityLevel, $cUser) {
    switch($visibilityLevel, $cUser)
    {
        case 0: return false;
        case 1: return true;
        case 2: return LOGGED_IN && isset($cUser);
        case 3: return !LOGGED_IN || !isset($cUser);
        default: throw new Exception('invalid visibility level.');
    }
}
```

And then use it as

```
    foreach($grabNav as $nav)
    {
        if(!isVisible($nav['visibility'], $cUser) || $nav['parent_id'] != -1) { continue; }
        [...]
```

Note also that I removed the useless default from the beginning of the switch, added it again at the end, and threw an exception for invalid values.

I also simplified cases 2 and 3 (`if (cond) true else false` can be phrased as `cond`), and I combined the two continue conditions.